# how to get the evaluated text of bash output

Tags: bash, text-processing

When I run a command line it prints some output, and some of the text is different colors and there is some other formatting going on. When I get the string programmatically, it has a bunch of control characters:

> The 'To' number +18 is not a valid phone number.\x1b[0m\n\n\x1b[37m\x1b[49m

printed directly out you get the text nicely formatted without all those control characters. If you highlight this text in putty and copy to notepad the text looks the same with the formatting removed.

How can I get the evaluated text without the formatting? is there any such program? If you use echo it just reprints out the formatted text and maintains the formatting so that doesn't work.

Comment: Those control characters may be invisible but they are actually in the output, so if you capture the output (by redirecting to a file, command substitution, or whatever), you're going to capture them too.   You need to filter them out somehow, using, e.g., `sed` or `perl`.  note that colour codes etc are fairly easy to strip, but some codes are used to do things like repositioning the cursor.  getting usable output from that is far more difficult.   that's why, for example, the `script` command has matching `scriptreplay` command to replay recorded terminal sessions.

Comment: I have tried a lot of examples to strip the codes, the problem is there are codes that need to be evaluated, like backspacing, and clear screen. I was hoping there was some library to eval what they are..... But I will look into sed ty

Comment: this is one of the reasons why most unix command-line tools don't use fancy formatting - the output is too valuable as potential input for another program to mess it up with difficult-to-strip garbage.   It's also why some programs (e.g. GNU `grep` and `diff`) have a `--color=WHEN` (where `WHEN` is auto, always, or never) option to control when it colourises output.  `auto` is the default and colourises output when it's going to the terminal, but not when it's being piped or redirected.

Comment: @noone392 you're going in the wrong direction. The right solution is to modify whatever is producing those strings to not add the escape sequences in  the first place (maybe there's an option? Maybe it needs a fix?), not to have that tool generate escape sequences and then have to write another tool to try to remove them again.